# 2 dimensional array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14

For declaring 2 dimensional array of pointers this is the code:

```
int x;
cin>>x;

int** pointerx = new int*[x];
for(int i = 0; i<x;i++){
    pointerx[i] = new int[x];
}
```

Since c++14 or through compiler extensions :

```
int* pointerx[x][x];
```

Are there any pitfalls in using  1st code instead of the 2nd or vice versa?

Comment: Use `vector<vector<int>>`

Comment: what if your employer asks you to write a container without using STL?

Comment: the first one and the second one are not the same. Look closely.

Comment: Convince them, or find a new employer, or find free vector reference code, muddle it up a bit, and include it and hope they don't notice.

Comment: @voltaa7 then you should implement your own vector class, because it really has better maintainability. If it a university task maintainability is non-important

Comment: @Arne can you please tell how are they different?

Comment: thanks for whoever did a -1 on my question , you java wussy …get back to your den .I hate it when people don't understand every question is important and yes I did my googling before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int* pointerx[x][x];` is not legal in C++14. It was added to early drafts but then removed well before the final specification.

The main pitfalls of using a compiler extension are:

- Your code may not work (or work differently) on other compilers, or on other versions of the same compiler.
- Usually there is no well-specified documentation of what the code does, so it is hard to get support if your code is not working.

If you look through the C standard for the text *variably modified type* you will see that it occurs in many places; the effect of allowing a variable-length array has a "butterfly effect" and it ends up influencing a lot of other things in the language.

For example, if `int* pointerx[x][x];` is permitted, does your compiler also support `int* (*y)[x] == pointerx;` and does it handle `sizeof *y` correctly?  Maybe it does; does your compiler documentation also describe that?

Comment: thanks for telling me its not a legal in c++14 , i thought it was.

Comment: no `int* (*y)[x] == pointerx` is giving an error and `sizeof *y` is working fine. What does this actually mean: `int* (*y)[x] == pointers`

Comment: coming back to the main question `int* pointer[x][x]` is a  variable length array, the compiler has allowed it through extension as i am still on c++11 ; does it offer any advantage in some scenarios (that is why it was included in the extension!).What are those scenarios?and what are the pitfalls?

Comment: I already listed the pitfalls (in my opinion). The pitfalls outweigh any advantage. You can use standard techniques instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first set of code is an int pointer pointer, you point to a pointer pointing to an int, or in this case an array of int pointers, so pointerx[i] wont actually hold an int, while the second bit of code will be a pointer to a 2D array of ints, so pointerx[i][i] will actually give you an int

feel free to comment if you need it explained better

Comment: Yes I want the explanation!